# why integral converges

Tags: probability-theory, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, sequence-of-function

Let $v$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $v$ has no atom. Let $\left(x^{i, N}\right)_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant N}$ be the sequence of real numbers defined by:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x^{1, N} & =\inf \left\{x \mid v((-\infty, x]) \geqslant \frac{1}{N+1}\right\} \\
x^{(i+1), N} & =\inf \left\{x \geqslant x^{i, N} \mid v\left(\left(x^{i, N}, x\right]\right) \geqslant \frac{1}{N+1}\right\} ,\quad 1 \leqslant i \leqslant (N-1) 
\end{aligned}
$$
We have,
$$
-\infty<x^{1, N}<x^{2, N}<\cdots<x^{N, N}<+\infty,
$$
How does following follows
$$
 \varliminf_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left\{ \int_{x^{1, N} \leqslant x<y \leqslant x^{N, N}} \log (y-x) \, dv(x) \, dv(y) \right\} \geqslant \frac{1}{2}\iint \log|y-x| \, dv(x) \, dv(y)
$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Why do you think this is true?

Comment: It seems like some convergence theorem, but again log is causing problem

Comment: Why does the log cause problems?